# Access to another requested input in custom rule class - Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I need to access `$request->important` in passes method. I need it to validate name based on this value

```
class TestCustom implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // 
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'some txt';
    }
}
```

**Used like this:**

```
use App\Rules\TestCustom;

$request->validate([
    'name' => ['required', new TestCustom],
    'important' => ['required', 'string'],
]);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's much better to pass data to rule constructor and use it inside rule afterwards. This way you can use rule to validate different data sources, in case if it comes not from request.

```
class TestCustom implements Rule
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // Use $this->data['important'] for validation
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'some txt';
    }
}
```

Then pass data to rule:

use App\Rules\TestCustom;

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => ['required', new TestCustom($request->all())],
    'important' => ['required', 'string'],
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `Input` facade-

```
Input::get('important');
```

Comment: What if data comes not only from request but from other sources?

Comment: I don't need to try it to see that it's bad idea, much better is to pass request data in rule constructor like new TestCustom($request->all()). Otherwise this rule will not be reusable with data validation from other sources.

Comment: Under Laravel >= 6.x this is now `Request::input('important');`. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#the-input-facade

Except this gives the error message "Non-static method Illuminate\\Http\\Request::input() should not be called statically" when used from an `implements Rule->passes()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel version ^8.0**

Laravel makes it very easy using `setData` method of `DataAwareRule` interface . [Document to access additional data](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)

```
    /**
     * Set the data under validation.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setData($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        return $this;
    }
```

**Complete Example :**

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\DataAwareRule;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class TestCustom  implements Rule, DataAwareRule
{

   
    protected $data = [];

    /**
     * Set the data under validation.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setData($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        return $this;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        dd($this->data);
    }
   
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The validation error message.';
    }
}
```