# Use Extra Parameter (Attribute) in Custom Rule for Request with Laravel Validation

Tags: php, laravel

I've seen this [Validating array in Laravel using custom rule with additional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963713/validating-array-in-laravel-using-custom-rule-with-additional-parameter) and it looks similar to the problem I have. However, the problem is that I'm using a separate Request to validate instead of validating in my controller. Here is the Request file:

```sh
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\APIFormRequest;
use App\Rules\TimeTooLate;

class ShowRequest extends APIFormRequest
{
...
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'start_time' => ['required', new TimeTooLate(':timezone')],
            'join_url' => 'required',
            'venue' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'timezone' => 'required'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            ...
        ];
    }

}
```

**I'm trying to pass 'timezone' into my custom rule.** Here is my Rule:

```sh
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use App\Traits\DateTimeTrait;

class TimeTooLate implements Rule
{
    use DateTimeTrait;

    public $tz;

    public function __construct(string $timezone)
    {
        $this->tz = $timezone;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if ($this->getDateDifferenceFromNow($value, $this->tz) >= 0){
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'It\'s too late to add this show now';
    }
}
```

As you can see, in order for my `getDateDifferenceFromNow` function to work, it needs the timezone passed in. What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried `request()->input('timezone')`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420488/access-to-another-requested-input-in-custom-rule-class-laravel

Comment: It wouldn't work @Kerkouch because I'm using a separate Request file to validate. I'm not validating in the controller.

Comment: My apologies @Kerkouch. You were absolutely right. In my mind I saw `$request->input` but never realized you were talking about the `request()` function. I realized it can even be shortened to `request('timezone')`. Didn't recognize my error until I saw the docs for making after validation hooks. If you make your comment into an official answer I'll mark it as best answer. Thnx.